# c++ days between two given dates

Tags: c++

So I've been struggling with this homework for a long time...
This still does not work and teachers comment was that I have to change the code and add set/get operators...
I tried by myself and it only got worse. Program only lets user to insert first date, output is completely wrong. Where I should start to fix it?

```
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Date
{
   private:
   int m;
   int d;
   int y;

   public:
   Date(int, int, int);
   int getLeapYears(Date&);
   int getDifference(Date&);
   int operator-(Date&);
 };

  int main()
  {
   int day, month, year;
   char c;

   cout << "Enter a start date (m/d/y): " << endl;
   cin >> month >> c >> day >> c >> year;

   Date start = Date(month, day, year);

   cout << "Enter an end date (m/d/y): " << endl;
   cin >> month >> c >> day >> c >> year;

   Date end = Date(month, day, year);
   int duration = end-start;

    cout << "The number of days between those two dates are: " <<
    duration << endl;

    return 0;
  }


   Date::Date(int a, int b, int c)
   {
   m = a;
   d = b;
   y = c;
   }

   const int monthDays[13] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,31,31,30,31};

  int Date::getLeapYears(Date& d)
  {
     int years = d.y;
     if (d.m <= 2)
     years--;
     return years / 4 - years / 100 + years / 400;
   }

  int Date::getDifference(Date& other)
  {

     int n1 = other.y*365 + other.d;

     for (int i=0; i<other.m - 1; i++)
    {
      n1 += monthDays[i];
      n1 += getLeapYears(other);
     }

     return n1;
     }

  int Date::operator-(Date& d) {
     int difference = getDifference(d);
     return difference;
   }
```

Comment: `getDifference` never uses `*this` for anything. As far as I can tell, it computes the age of `other` in days, since the beginning of time. This computation is useful for computing the difference, but you need to do it twice (put it in its own function).

Comment: As a side note, I don't see any point in breaking the abstraction with getters and setters.

Comment: `monthDays` is incorrect for september

Answer (score 0):

`getDifference` calculates the number of days since year 0. Obviously if you have two dates you can calculate the total number of days since year 0 for each and subtract these two totals and that is the number of days between your dates. I'm sure you know this.

Now ask yourself the following.

How many times do you call `getDifference`? Obviously it needs to be called for each date, but is that what happens?

Where in your code do you perform the subtraction of the two day totals as described above?

Is `getDifference` a good name for a function which calculates the number of days since year 0? Wouldn't `getTotalDays` (or something) be better?

You've clearly confused yourself with your own code, its not doing what you wanted it to do. Spending the time to choose meaningful names for your functions is one important way not to confuse yourself about your own code.

Here's the kind of rewrite I'm suggesting

```
int Date::getLeapYears()
{
     int years = y;
     if (m <= 2)
         years--;
     return years / 4 - years / 100 + years / 400;
}

int Date::getTotalDays()
{
     int n1 = y*365 + d;
     for (int i=0; i<m - 1; i++)
     {
         n1 += monthDays[i];
         n1 += getLeapYears();
     }
     return n1;
}

int Date::operator-(Date& d) {
    int difference = getTotalDays() - d.getTotalDays();
    return difference;
}
```

Not saying that will fix every bug (I haven't checked) but notice the improvements, I've renamed `getDifference` as `getTotalDays` and now it is called **twice** and the results are subtracted. I've also removed the `other` parameter from `getTotalDays` and `getLeapYears`. These methods now operate on the current `this` object not on a parameter.

Seems likely that it was the switch from `operator-` (which operates on two dates) to `getTotalDays` and `getLeapYears` (which operate on only one date) that was confusing you.